# Derivation of number of elements drawn to obtain probability in generalized birthday problem

Tags: probability, exponential-function

I'm reading the wikipedia page for the [generalized birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#The_generalized_birthday_problem).  I have a question about the derivation,

Under the *Cast as a collision problem* section, they write,

$$p(n;d) \approx 1 - e^{-n(n-1)/(2d)}$$
$$p(n;d) \approx 1 - (\frac{d-1}{d})^{n(n-1)/2}$$

This transformation is done using the limit for $e^x = (1+\frac{x}{n})^n$, with $x=\frac{-1}{d}$ and $n=1$ right?

But I can't figure out the next transformation for $n(p;d)$, eg.

$$n(p;d) \approx \sqrt{2d * \ln(\frac{1}{1-p})}$$

Could anyone explain how that was derived there?

Comment: For the first, they have actually used the approximation $e^x\approx 1+x$ with $x=-\frac1d$.

Comment: right, that is what I have there, since n=1

Comment: They're different expansions. If we are using $(1+\frac xn)^n\to e^x$, in order to be able to say $(1+\frac xn)^n\approx e^x$ we would need $n$ to be large. On the other hand, the Taylor expansion $1+x+O(x^2)$ is valid for sufficiently small $x$, or sufficiently large $d$ in our case.

Comment: @Jason ah, I see, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p \approx 1 - \left(\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^{n(n-1)/2}$$

so
$$\left(\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^{n(n-1)/2} \approx 1-p  $$

so
$$\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\log\left(\frac{d-1}{d}\right) \approx \log(1-p)  $$

so 
$${n(n-1)} \approx \dfrac{2\log(1-p)}{\log\left(\frac{d-1}{d}\right)}  $$

and saying $1-\frac1d \approx e^{-d}$ i.e. $\log\left(\frac{d-1}{d}\right) \approx -\frac1d$, and $\log(1-p)=-\log\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)$
$${n(n-1)} \approx 2d\log\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right) $$

and saying $\sqrt{n(n-1)}\approx n $
$$n \approx \sqrt{2d\log\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)} $$